# More concise way to check for Integers in ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

Is there a shorter alternative to sequentially checking multiple `&&` conditions in an ArrayList?

```
if (mList.contains(0) && mList.contains(1) && mList.contains(2)) {
    // TODO: Do I really have to do it like this?
};
```

Or can I do something like this?

```
    Integer[] condition1 = {0, 1, 2};
        for (Integer item : condition1) {
            if (mXPositions.containsAll(item)) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.player_1_wins, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (mOPositions.contains(item)) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.player_2_wins, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
     }
```

Comment: Why the `for` in the second alternative? Just `mXPositions.containsAll(condition1))`

Comment: ``List<Integer> mXPositions`` is a ListArray of Integers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this shorter through `Arrays.asList()`, which takes in a varagrs argument:

```
if (mList.containsAll(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2)))
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is what I meant on my comment ;)